# Logs for Windows XP and Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, shutdown, logging

Where can I find the last time the system was properly or improperly shutdown through the logs of Windows XP and Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Best Solution

You first need to enable the *Shutdown Event Tracker*. Steps for both Windows 2003 and XP are found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293814). Afterwards you just go to the event viewer and check it from there. An overview of it can be found here at [Microsoft's TechNet Overview of Shutdown Event Tracker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757754(WS.10).aspx).

#### Work Around

If you are looking for that improper shutdown that has already accrued then that is a little harder. If you are able to find the GroupPolicy Opertional log then what you could do is look for key words: *StartShell* and *EndShell*. If you see two *StartShell* for the same session with a *EndShell* between it then you know that it was shutdown incorrectly. Windows wouldn't be able to EndShell for session if the power was suddenly interrupted.

*Note: I found the workaround solution on a Windows 7 system. I don't know if XP or 2003 has this too.*

Comment: "By default, Shutdown Event Tracker is enabled for all Windows Server 2003 operating systems and for Windows XP 64-Bit Edition Version 2003."..."By default, Shutdown Event Tracker is disabled in Windows XP Professional."